# Smart Search to search in archived articles

Tags: search, joomla

How can I extend Smart Search so it searches not only in published articles, but also in archived?
In the indexed pages I see an archived article, but it doesn't come up in the results.
I've duplicated the content plugin for smart search, but can't find the line to edit for searching in archived articles.